# Is the crazyflie control board considered a microcontroller

Tags: quadcopter

I am currently doing a project for school and we are told that we must use a micro controller that ends up controlling some external hardware, now i know the crazyflie is controlling the motors which counts as external hardware but is it a micro controller? My second question is i want to purchase the kit so i can assembly it myself however I saw that you can use an expansion board so you need not solder and also i plan on not buying a remote its possible to control the crazyflie via my iPhone correct? I would appreciate it if someone could answer my questions. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your school intends for you to *program* the microcontroller, in which case the crazyflie -- an off-the-shelf product -- would not be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The crazyflie comes ready to use with their iPhone and Android App, no extra components required. But the idea is that you can develop and make changes so if you wanted (depending on the precise outline of your project) you could use it for your project but program it yourself to do something in addition to the out of the box functionality, or add extra hardware like the LED component to perform some form of light show as you fly it, or automate some flight instructions.

It is worth noting that the source code for the app's are also available.